# Help a beginner solve a differentials eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to determine whether the function defined implicitly by: 
$$x^2 + y^2 = 9$$ 
is a solution of the differential equation: 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x}{y}.$$  Please explain each step in process. I would like to very much understand the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually have to solve the differential equation to verify that the given function is a solution. What you need to do is "plug in" the proposed solution into the differential equation and see if you get the right answer. If you do, then it's a solution. If you don't, then it's not a solution.

But this is not "really" a differential equation anyway. What you need to do is compute the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ using [**implicit differentiation.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_and_explicit_functions#Implicit_differentiation)

To do that, just differentiate with respect to $x$ both sides of the equation, using the usual differentiation rules; *but* you must remember that $y$ is "really" a function of $x$, so that you should use the Chain Rule whenever you are differentiating an expression involving $y$. Since you don't know what $y'$ is explicitly, you leave it indicated.

Once you are done, you "solve for $y'$".

Let me do a different example so you can see how it is done. Suppose you want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the function defined implicitly by
$$x^3+y^3 = 3xy.$$
(The folium of Descartes)
First, we take derivatives on both sides, remembering to use the Chain Rule; I'll do each term separately:
$$\begin{align*}
x^3 + y^3 &= 3xy\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left( x^3+y^3\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy\\
\frac{d}{dx}x^3 + \frac{d}{dx}y^3 &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy &&\text{(since }(f+g)'=f'+g'\text{)}\\
3x^2 + \frac{d}{dx}y^3 &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy &&\text{(since }(x^3)'=3x^2\text{)}\\
3x^2 + 3y^2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy &&\text{(using the Chain Rule)}\\
3x^2 + 3y^2y' &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy &&\text{(we don't know what }\frac{dy}{dx}\text{ is, so leave indicated)}\\
3x^2 + 3y^2y' &= 3\frac{d}{dx}(xy) &&\text{(since }(3f)' = 3f'\text{)}\\
3x^2+3y^2y' &= 3\left( x'y + xy'\right) &&\text{(product rule)}\\
3x^2 +3y^2y' &= 3(y+xy') &&\text{(since }x'=1\text{)}\\
3x^2 + 3y^2y' &=3y + 3xy'
\end{align*}$$
Now, solve for $y'$:
$$\begin{align*}
3x^2 + 3y^2y' &= 3y+3xy'\\
3y^2y' - 3xy' &= 3y - 3x^2\\
3(y^2-x)y' &= 3(y-x^2)\\
y' &= \frac{3(y-x^2)}{3(y^2-x)}\\
y' &= \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}.
\end{align*}$$
So for the Folium of Descartes, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$.

That's what you need to do to see whether $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the circle of radius $3$ and center at the origin is equal to $\frac{y}{x}$; but it will be *much* easier than the above, so if you can follow the derivation here, your problem should be a snap.

Comment: Can you please expand on the following steps please.          3x^2 + 3y^2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}3xy &&\text{(using the Chain Rule)}\\                                                   when you use Chain rule, why do you leave the 3y^2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) in this when you didn't do that for the first.

Comment: @user10695: $y$ is really a function of $x$; if we write it as $f(x)$ (instead of $y$), then it becomes clearer. We have $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2$; how is this done? By using the Chain Rule: $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2 = 2(f(x))*f'(x)$. Since $y=f(x)$, then $f'(x) = y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$. In fact I **did** do it "for the first", it's just that in that case you get $\frac{dx}{dx}$, which equals $1$, and of course multiplying by $1$ is the same as doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_differentiation#Implicit_differentiation)?  You can differentiate using the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) giving $2x+2yy'=0$ and see if it satisfies $y'=\frac{x}{y}$

Comment: Alas, I am too late and too redundant!

Comment: When I took the derivative of $$x^2 + y^2 = 9$$ , I got $2x+2y =0$  instead. May I ask how you got your answer please?

Comment: He used the chain rule, like he said! You could write, after differentiating both sides *with respect to x*, $2xx' + 2yy' = 0$, but keep in mind that $x' = \frac{dx}{dx} = 1$, so that's why it doesn't appear in his answer.

Comment: @The Chaz:  I was elsewhere at the time.  You got it.  Thanks.

Comment: You were probably beating me to the punch elsewhere! :)